# Inspect on-the-fly generated element on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, combobox, inspect

I'm trying to inspect 2nd combo box which its values are generated on the fly through 1st combo box ajax on changed event.

The values are loaded successfully, but I can't inspect the values. I want to get all the text (Chinese), and it can't be accessed from other browsers except IE.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer: Press refresh button of the Developer Tools and re-inspect the element.